# multi_index template compiling error

Tags: c++, templates, multi-index

2 Questions:
1. Do i really need to pass parameter to modify/modify_key via member?
2. Why do i have this compilation error

To see the entire code with the error, you can look at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6241361318e1925

the error is

```
MultiIndex4.h: In member function 'uint32_t CrMultiParameterMultiIndex::ModifyKeyBy(SearchingKey&, ModifyKeyType&) [with SearchingTagType = IMEI_tag, ModifyingTagType = IMEI_tag, SearchingKey = uint32_t, ModifyKeyType = uint32_t]':
MultiIndex4.h:183:   instantiated from here
MultiIndex4.h:119: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<UsersKey, UsersKey_indices, std::allocator<UsersKey> >::modify_key(boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<UsersKey, std::allocator<UsersKey> > > >&, boost::function<void ()(uint32_t&)>&)'
*** Errors occurred during this build ***
```

I have a class CrMultiParameterMultiIndex that hold a multi-index that have 2 indexes.

I tried to create a template function that search only according a part of the key and modify only a part of the key.

This class have a helper function

```
template <typename TagType,typename SearchingKey>
typename GlobalHash::index<TagType>::type::iterator GetIteratorBy(SearchingKey & key){
    return  m_pGlobalHash->get<TagType>().find(key) ;
}
```

and modify function that use it

```
template <typename SearchingTagType,typename ModifyingTagType,typename SearchingKey,typename ModifyKeyType> uint32_t ModifyKeyBy(SearchingKey & key,ModifyKeyType & pi_Modifykey)
    {
    uint32_t hRes = 1;

    //search for entry by TagType
    typedef  typename GlobalHash::index<SearchingTagType>::type     IndexType;
    typename IndexType::iterator it =  GetIteratorBy<SearchingTagType>(key);

    //entry found
    if( it != m_pGlobalHash->get<SearchingTagType>().end() )
    {
        //Set parameter to modify
        hRes = SetParameterKeys<ModifyingTagType>(pi_Modifykey);

        if(hRes == 1)
        {
            //get iteraror to modify
            typedef  typename GlobalHash::index<ModifyingTagType>::type     ModifyIndexType;
            typename ModifyIndexType::iterator itToModify =  m_pGlobalHash->get<ModifyingTagType>().iterator_to(*it);

            boost::function<void( ModifyKeyType &)> f = boost::bind(&CrMultiParameterMultiIndex::ModifyKey<ModifyingTagType, ModifyKeyType >, this, _1);

            //modify key failed
            if(m_pGlobalHash->modify_key(itToModify , f)==false)
                hRes = 0;
        }
    }
    //entry not found
    else
        hRes = 0;
    return hRes;
}
```

this compile

```
uint64_t nFromImsi = 1;
uint64_t nToImsi = 1;
m_multiParam.ModifyKeyBy<IMSI_tag,IMSI_tag>( nFromImsi,nToImsi)
```

but not this

```
uint32_t nFromImsi = 1;
uint32_t nToImsi = 1;
m_multiParam.ModifyKeyBy<IMEI_tag,IMEI_tag>( nFromImsi,nToImsi)
```

Why? and how can it compile

and here are the modifiers

```
template <> inline void CrMultiParameterMultiIndex::ModifyKey<IMEI_tag>( uint32_t & po_Key){po_Key = m_ParameterKeys.IMEI;}
template <> inline void CrMultiParameterMultiIndex::ModifyKey<IMSI_tag>(uint64_t & po_Key){po_Key = m_ParameterKeys.IMSI;}
```

Answer (score 2):

David,

The problem with

```
if(m_pGlobalHash->modify_key(itToModify , f)==false)
```

lies in the fact that `m_pGlobalHash`is a view to index #0 (`order_by_IMSI`) and does not accept iterators to view #1 (`order_by_IMEI`). You can either [project iterators](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#projection) or select the appropriate index:

```
if(m_pGlobalHash->get<ModifyingTagType>().modify_key(itToModify , f)==false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do i really need to pass parameter to modify/modify_key via member?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question about passing parameters "via member", care to elaborate?

Comment: modify_key/modify receive reference to the key, but not a new value to set to this key. So if i have a new value to set to the key i need to set it in a member, call modify, and in the callback read the value from member. For example in my code i save the key i want to change via SetParameterKeys and in ModifyKey i read it back.

Comment: I can't follow the logic of your program, but I guess you can simply do something like (using lambdas) 

    m_pGlobalHash->get<ModifyingTagType>().modify_key(itToModify, [&pi_Modifykey](ModifyKeyType & k){k=pi_Modifykey});

Comment: Is this possible without lambda i didn't learn lambda yet + not working with c++11

Comment: You can use something like the `set_value` thing shown at: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b686fa23d76f92